Stream cloud functions without activating Blaze (pay-as-you-go)
I published the frondent part with Firebase hosting, but there are API and data in the backend part, it says to activate Blaze Cloud functions, can someone give me an idea if I can publish the backend part without activating Firebase Blaze Plan?
When I run this  firebase deploy --only functions
I got this error:

Your project id s must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete. To upgrade, visit the following URL:


It's Google, not Santa.

If you want to interact with your functions you can emulate them in any Firebase project.
Now, you're getting the following error:

Your project id s must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command.

When running this command:

firebase deploy --only functions

Because in order to deploy your functions, your project must be on the Blaze Plan. There is no way you can avoid that. For more info, please see Cloud Functions pricing.

Hey Barış. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
